# Is/could "noctophyte" be a word?

Tags: suffixes, is-it-a-word, prefixes, greek

Let me preface this by saying that I am trying to come up with an interesting-sounding name for gamedev purposes. I'm looking for a potentially imaginary word that can be given a logical definition.

---

*"[Heliophyte](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/heliophyte)"* is a word that seems to be the combination of the prefix *"helio"* (meaning sun) and *"phyte"* (meaning seed or plant), and is defined as (according to dictionary.com) a plant that grows best in sunlight. While browsing [this list](http://www.prefixsuffix.com/rootchart.php) I discovered the prefix *"noct"* (meaning night), which I attempted to swap with the prefix from *"heliophyte"* to form a word with the opposite meaning: *"noctophyte"* (plant that grows best in the night). I'm not really sure where I got the 'o' from, it just *sounds* better than inserting another vowel such as 'i' or 'e' (I'm assuming you would need to add a vowel since *"noct"* ends in a consonant). Google returns zero results for *"noctophyte"*, so it seems the word does not exist.

I.e. "A sunflower can be classified as a type of *heliophyte*." "A moon flower can be classified as a type of *noctophyte*." (I have no idea if that is factually correct)

**[I chose the English Language & Usage forum because I'm more interested in the construction/creation of such a word than the biological classification/equivalent.]**

Is there a word similar to what I am looking for? If not, could *"noctophyte"* be a grammatically correct, imaginary term?

Comment: If it's a word, Google will almost certainly find it.  And you can tell from the contexts where it's found whether it's a "real" word, or just someone mucking around, or perhaps a misspelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you google ***nyctophyte*** you'll see that at least one other person ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldbuilding/comments/2vak4i/what_are_the_narcotics_of_your_world/)) has used this term to describe flowers that thrive in darkness (for example, underground in caves).

But the neologism ***noctophyte*** works too since "nocto-" is an acceptable prefix meaning night ([here](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/noct-,+nocti-,+nocto-,+noctu-)). Although see the caveats of @sumelic in the comments below.

Comment: Aw, I just upvoted you and then you made an edit I disagree with! *Nyctophyte*  is better than *noctophyte* because *noct-* is a Latin root, and besides the fact that *noctophyte* would be a mixed word (which isn't a big deal in itself, there are a lot of those) Latin roots normally get the linking vowel *-i-* rather than *-o-* (you can see it in *noctilucent*). I'm sure *nocto-* has been used, but it doesn't look right to me. This is still a good answer; I just felt compelled to leave this pedantic comment.

Comment: @sumelic, good points. I made an edit to point to them. The only word I could find with "nocto" is *noctograph*, some kind of instrument used by the blind invented circa 1800. Probably the name was coined for the occasion. Shame they didn't have EL&U back then!

Answer (score 1):

Silenus's suggestion of *nyctophyte* is very good. I was looking to see if there are any alternatives, and found the following words:

[scotophyte](http://wordinfo.info/results/scotophyte) (from Greek *skotos* "darkness"):

> a plant living in darkness

(English Word Information)

[sciophyte](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sciophyte), also spelled *[sciaphyte](https://books.google.com/books?id=x_wHxTE-cEsC&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=sciaphyte&source=bl&ots=62PfYkCtvO&sig=6VgVC0zURHDgR-XO1O7OKWe19cE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkjeqIsd7KAhVM92MKHb2dDAo4ChDoAQhCMAc#v=onepage&q=sciaphyte&f=false), skiophyte* (from Greek *skia* "shadow, shade"; according to the Oxford English Dictionary, the variation between *-a-* and *-o-* in the combining form dates back to Greek):

> Any plant that tolerates or thrives in a low light level (shade)

(Wiktionary)